# Late taking birth control pill

Tags: obstetrics, sex, contraception

I've been taking the combined birth control pill for the past two months, but I've been away (in another country) for Christmas and I forgot to take the third batch with me. When I got home, I took it immediately.
Ideally, I should have taken it on Tuesday at lunch, but this time I started the batch on Wednesday at dinner.

I know I was only one day late, but can I get pregnant if I have sex now without a condom? How long should I wait until the pill takes effect?

Comment: If you started the pack late, you need alternate contraception for 7 days. http://www.thehealthsite.com/sexual-health/will-i-get-pregnant-if-i-miss-taking-the-birth-control-pill-query-of-the-day/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Birth control pills omitted for one day and having unprotected sex will not result in pregnancy if you have taken missed pill and the pill you  should been taking on Wednesday. 
Birth control pills are comprised of sex hormones and work by suppressing ovulation. One day missing dosage of birth control pills is not enough for ovulation recovery as shown by researches.

Here is one of the researches that looks at omission of birth control pills for three days and more and its effect on ovulation: 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/9704763/

However there may be the psychological moment overcoming the fear of getting pregnant then having protected sex can be an option to be worry free.